# Can't sort ArrayList with multiple objects by one of the specific objects (java)

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, alphabetical-sort

I wish to sort by name but am unable to figure out how to do so

```
private void displayTasks(List<Task> tasks) {
    List priority1 = new ArrayList();
    List priority2 = new ArrayList();
    List priority3 = new ArrayList();
    List priority4 = new ArrayList();
    List priority5 = new ArrayList();
    for (int i = 0; i < tasks.size(); i++) {
        Task task = (Task)tasks.get(i);
        int priority = task.getPriority();
        String name = task.getName();
        String description = task.getDescription();
        int index = i;
        if (priority == 1){
            priority1.add(task);
            this.taskCollection.updateTask(index, name, description, priority);
```

the problem seems to be with Collections.sort(priority1), I would like it to now sort priority1 alphabetically(same with the other priorities) using name but am unsure on how to do so and nothing I have found works

```
            Collections.sort(priority1);
        }
        if (priority == 2){
            priority2.add(task);
            this.taskCollection.updateTask(index, name, description, priority);
            Collections.sort(priority2);
        }
        if (priority == 3){
            priority3.add(task);
            this.taskCollection.updateTask(index, name, description, priority);
            Collections.sort(priority3);
        }
        if (priority == 4){
            priority4.add(task);
            this.taskCollection.updateTask(index, name, description, priority);
            Collections.sort(priority4);
        }
        if (priority == 5){
            priority5.add(task);
            this.taskCollection.updateTask(index, name, description, priority);
            Collections.sort(priority5);
        }

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < priority1.size(); i++) {
        Task task = (Task)priority1.get(i);
        System.out.println("Name: " + task.getName()  + ", Description: " + task.getDescription() + ", Priority: 1" );
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < priority2.size(); i++) {
        Task task = (Task)priority2.get(i);
        System.out.println("Name: " + task.getName()  + ", Description: " + task.getDescription() + ", Priority: 2" );
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < priority3.size(); i++) {
        Task task = (Task)priority3.get(i);
        System.out.println("Name: " + task.getName()  + ", Description: " + task.getDescription() + ", Priority: 3" );
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < priority4.size(); i++) {
        Task task = (Task)priority4.get(i);
        System.out.println("Name: " + task.getName()  + ", Description: " + task.getDescription() + ", Priority: 4" );
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < priority5.size(); i++) {
        Task task = (Task)priority5.get(i);
        System.out.println("Name: " + task.getName()  + ", Description: " + task.getDescription() + ", Priority: 5" );
    }

    }
```

when two things of the same priority are added I receive these set of errors

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.greene.project2.Task cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
at java.util.ComparableTimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(ComparableTimSort.java:320)
at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:188)
at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1312)
at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1506)
at java.util.ArrayList.sort(ArrayList.java:1454)
at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:141)
at com.greene.project2.TaskView.displayTasks(Main.java:164)
at com.greene.project2.TaskView.list(Main.java:212)
at com.greene.project2.TaskView.menu(Main.java:247)
at com.greene.project2.TaskView.run(Main.java:257)
at com.greene.project2.Main.main(Main.java:267)
```

Comment: `Task` does not implement `Comparable` interface

Comment: Never use raw types. List<Task> instead of List.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of two solutions:

First one would be to Task to implement [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) interface. But this bounds sorting order with your model, so it can be troublesome in the future.

Second would be to pass a Comparator to your sort methods.

```
Lists.sort(priority4, Comparator.compareBy(Task::getName));
```

Second solution would allow you to change the order in runtime, so it would be more preferable.

Small improvement:

```
private void displayTasks(List<Task> tasks) {
    List<Task> priority1 = new ArrayList<>(); // use generics here
    ...
    for (int i = 0; i < tasks.size(); i++) {
        Task task = tasks.get(i); // casting is redundant, as tasks is a list of Tasks
```

This way you will avoid unnecessary casting.

Answer (score 0):

Check for this line in your code.

```
Collections.sort(priority5);
```

The `sort` method in `java.util.Collections` class expects a `List` that contains objects of class implementing `Comparable` interface.

So, Define your `Task` class such that, it implements `Comprable` interface.